# Showing that $\langle x^2 +y^2 -1 \rangle$ is a radical ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think I've got a grasp on how theorems and definitions tie into each other with respect to radical ideals, function algebras, the Nulstellensatz etc... but I'm still stumped on how to actually explicitly show something like

$$I_1 = \langle x^2+y^2-1\rangle $$

is radical in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. In particular, I'm trying to do so by showing the quotient

$$\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle{x^2+y^2-1\rangle}$$

is reduced, but I'm not sure how to actually do that. Alternatively I know that an equivalent condition is for an ideal $I_2 = \langle f \rangle $ be generated by a polynomial with no multiple roots, but that doesn't work here, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb C[x,y]$ is a unique factorisation domain. Any ideal in a UFD generated by a square-free element is radical. The polynomial
$x^2+y^2-1$ is not just square-free, but also irreducible.

Comment: Gonna have to look up a proof of that first statement, haven't come across that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $h=x^2+y^2-1$ is irreducible (by inspection if you try to write it as a product of linear factors) hence prime because $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is a UFD. Now remember that a ring is reduced exactly when it has no nonzero elements that square to zero, and if $h$ divides $f^2$ then $h$ must divide $f$ by primeness, and you are done.

Comment: That makes sense, although could you elaborate on the "by inspection" bit?

Comment: @AdrianHindes By that I mean, write $h = L_1L_2$ with $L_i$ a line and obtain some equations of the coefficients of the $L_i$ that cannot possibly hold.